# Laravel 5.1 ignores any values inside env()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am uisn glravel 5.1 and setting up mail service with Mailgun.  I've just found that my services file contains lines like the following:

```
'mailgun' => [
    'domain' => env('<domain>'),
    'secret' => env('<key>'),
],
```

Now for some reason, these values get ignored as-is.  However, if I remove the env() method from the above, it works.  So now I have this:

```
'mailgun' => [
    'domain' => '<domain>',
    'secret' => '<key>',
],
```

**Can anyone explain why this is?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because by

```
env('foo');
```

You are asking for the content of the "foo" constant defined in the .env file. Do you have a constant in your .env file named 'foo'?